# Regex to match a number without a certain suffix

Tags: python, regex

I have the following three strings:

```
inputs = [
    "Season 12",
    "Season 1a",
    "Season 1-2"
]
```

I am trying to match the first one only. Here is the current regex I have:

```
outputs = []
for input in inputs:
    output = re.search(r'(Staffel|Season|Saison|S\.?)?\s?(\d{0,})(?!(-|[a-z][A-Z]))', input, re.IGNORECASE).group(2)
    outputs.append(output)

assert(outputs == ['12','',''])
# AssertionError, values were ['12', '1', '']
```

Currently this works for `Season 12`, `Season 1-2`, but not `Season 1a` (it shouldn't return anything).

Comment: Why not just stipulate it be followed only by numbers.. I mean based on your example. `(Staffel|Season|Saison[\s]*?[\d]+)`

Comment: Can you just terminate the search with `$`? `^(Staffel|Season|Saison|S\.?)?\s?(\d*)$`

Comment: @FailSafe from the above example, yes. I should add in a few more inputs of a few trickier situations, such as "Seinfeld, Season 1 (UHD)" -- so basically everything after the number but before a space.

Comment: Hmmm, you want it to match `Seinfeld, Season 1` or do you want to match `Seinfeld, Season 1 (UHD)`? Not sure what you meant by "**everything** after the number but before a space"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want for `Seinfeld, Season 1 (UHD)`. Here it capture but if you don't want it, change the last part from `(?:\s|$)` to a simple `$`

```
import re

inputs = [
    "Season 12",
    "Season 1a",
    "Season 1-3",
    "Seinfeld, Season 1 (UHD)",
    "Seinfeld, Season 1"
]

outputs = []
for input in inputs:
    output = re.search(r'(?:Staffel|Season|Saison|S\.?)?\s(\d+)(?:\s|$)', input, re.IGNORECASE)
    if (output != None):
        outputs.append(output.group(1))
    else:
        outputs.append('')

print(outputs)
assert(outputs == ['12','','','1','1'])
```

**Output:**

```
['12', '', '', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
inputs = [
    "Season 12",
    "Season 1a",
    "Season 1-2",
    "Seinfeld, Season 1 (UHD)"
]
re_num = re.compile(
    r'(Staffel|Season|Saison|S\.?)\s?((\d+)$|(\d+)\s)',
    flags=re.IGNORECASE
)

for s in inputs:
    m = re_num.search(s)
    if m:
        print(s, '-->', m.group(2))
```

result:

```
Season 12 --> 12
Seinfeld, Season 1 (UHD) --> 1
```